# Quick one about static local variables in js

Tags: javascript, performance

I read you could simulate static local variables in js like this:

```
function count() {
count.i++;
}
count.i = 0;
```

Is storing 'i' as a property of 'count' faster than using a global? eg.

```
var i=0;
function count ()
{i++;
}
```

Just a performance comparison question.

Thanks.

Comment: For performance-related JavaScript questions, simply create [a jsPerf test case](http://jsperf.com/) and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems an externally stored value is faster. See [this test](http://jsperf.com/static-vs-outside-variable). It matters if you assign `count.i` within the function or outside. Assigning it outside the function shows a small difference. I wouldn't worry about that.

You can also consider this to emulate something static (added to the jsperf-test, it's roughly as fast as assigning a global variable or an externally assigned `count.i`)

```
function counter(){
 var i = 0;
 return {
     count:    function(){i += 1;},
     toString: function(){return i;},
     valueOf:  function(){return i;}
 };
}

var foo = counter(), bar = counter();
foo.count();
bar.count();
bar.count();
console.log(bar); //=> 2
console.log(foo); //=> 1
```

Comment: Just a note before we conclude externals are faster, when I do the test in Chrome, the first static test is faster than the external test by roughly 25%.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically the global variable should be slightly faster than the property, as the property lookup needs another step.

However, performance can differ quite a lot between different browsers, and accessing variables and properties is such fast operations that any performance difference there will rarely matter. Most other things that you do in a script will take a lot longer.